# Determine whether a ListView has been displayed it's own and DEFAULT VerticalScrollbar?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, listview

I need to determine in my control whether it has been displayed it's integrated **DEFAULT** `VerticalScrollbar`, I remark the **DEFAULT** part 'cause all the solutions that I've seen are for inherited user-controls that uses custom VScrolls, but really I'm not pretending to mess with a custom VScrollbar just to determine a value indicating its pressence inside the client area.

I've tried [this suggested solution](http://vbcity.com/forums/t/84147.aspx), but is not working at least with a Listview that uses it's default Scrollbars, I mean that the Controls collection always is Zero even when the VerticalScrollbar exists.

Also I've tried [this other solution](http://www.csharp-examples.net/check-scrollbars-visibility/), but seems that does not work for Listviews 'cause it can't recognize a ListView as an `ScrollableControl`, so strange.

**Note:** The size of my Listview is not static, I mean I've specified the anchor property so the listview is resized together when the Form resizes then also I think that a trick of an arithmetic formula measuring the width of all the columns and etc. to determine the pressence of the Scrollbar maybe will not be an efficient way (I don't know if could be).

**Note 2:** I can inherit the ListView control if it's needed to determine this, but as I've said I preffer to avoid the usage of a custom VScroll, I don't need it and that will provoke other questions that I want to prevent 'cause I'm not experienced with the usage of custom scrollbars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can at any given time check if a control has a `WS_VSCROLL` or `WS_HSCROLL` [window style](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632600(v=vs.85).aspx) by invoking [GetWindowLong](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633584(v=vs.85).aspx) and/or [GetWindowLongPtr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633585(v=vs.85).aspx).

```vb
'Private Const WS_VSCROLL As Integer = &H200000
'Private Const WS_HSCROLL As Integer = &H100000
'Private Const GWL_STYLE As Integer = -16

<DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint:="GetWindowLong", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> _
Private Shared Function GetWindowLong32(ByVal hWnd As HandleRef, ByVal nIndex As Integer) As IntPtr
End Function

<DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint:="GetWindowLongPtr", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> _
Private Shared Function GetWindowLong64(ByVal hWnd As HandleRef, ByVal nIndex As Integer) As IntPtr
End Function

Public Shared Function GetScrollbars(ctl As Control) As ScrollBars
    If (ctl Is Nothing) Then Throw New ArgumentNullException("ctl")
    Dim horizontal As Boolean = False
    Dim vertical As Boolean = False
    If (IntPtr.Size = 4) Then
        Dim style As Integer = GetWindowLong32(New HandleRef(ctl, ctl.Handle), -16I).ToInt32()
        horizontal = ((style And &H100000I) = &H100000I)
        vertical = ((style And &H200000I) = &H200000I)
    Else
        Dim style As Long = GetWindowLong64(New HandleRef(ctl, ctl.Handle), -16I).ToInt64()
        horizontal = ((style And &H100000L) = &H100000L)
        vertical = ((style And &H200000L) = &H200000L)
    End If
    If (horizontal AndAlso vertical) Then
        Return ScrollBars.Both
    ElseIf (horizontal) Then
        Return ScrollBars.Horizontal
    ElseIf (vertical) Then
        Return ScrollBars.Vertical
    End If
    Return ScrollBars.None
End Function
```

Comment: MSDN says that we should use GetWindowLongPtr instead to get x86/x64 compatibility, but well people has benn marked this as "Duplicate" so I can't provide an actual and documented solution for others.

Comment: @ElektroStudios You're absolutely right, that *is* preferable. I've update the answer to include 64 bit support. I'll give you a +1 for noticing this.