# Force the display of scroll bars in a ListView?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, pinvoke, scrollbars

- **The background**: Most of us know the `SysListView32` common control and the equivalent wrapper `ListView` class provided by the *.NET Framework*. A little depth into its internals show that the scroll bars it provides for scrolling its contents are ***NOT** controls themselves*, but are managed by the `SysListView32` control.
- **The goal**: Always draw scroll bars even if it has no `ListViewItems` to display or has very few such that no scroll bars are needed anyway; sort of like mimicking the `RichTextBox` class with its `ScrollBars` property set to `ForcedBoth`. Or kinda like this `ListBox`:

  [image: What I want...]

---

- **The problem(s)**:

  1. *.NET* has ***NO** sugar* at all for scroll bars within a `ListView`.
  2. Win32 documentation does not state when to *show/hide* and/or *enable/disable* scrollbars.
- **My workaround(s)**:

  1. `override` the `WndProc` in a derived class and handle its `WM_HSCROLL` and `WM_VSCROLL` messages as per steps 2 and 3.
  2. Call `base.WndProc` to do the actually required processing of the scroll functionality.
  3. Create a method like `WmScroll` and do *my* processing on it immediately `after` `base.WndProc` has returned.
  4. This consists of a p/invoke call  to `GetScrollInfo`. Determine if a scroll bar is actually needed. If it's not then call `ShowScrollBar` and `EnableScrollBar` with required values to draw visibly disabled scroll bars.
- **Problems with the workaround**:

  1. It barely works. The scroll bars are displayed and disabled but are like the ones under *Windows Classic Theme*.
  2. It hides the collapse buttons of each `ListViewGroup`, rendering them useless!

The descriptive image:

[image: This hides the beautiful collapse buttons (and looks awful)!]

---

***The long awaited actual question***:

***How do I force scroll bars to always be*** `Visible` ***within a*** `ListView` ***irrespective of the number of*** `ListViewItems` ***and disable them if they are unnecessary, at the same time avoiding size miscalculation*** *(to display collapse buttons of the* `ListViewGroup`*s)* ***and theme deterioration?***

Answers without code, and answers with code in **C#**, **VB.NET** and **C++/CLR** are welcome. If you post code in any other language supported by .NET, please also leave a link to a code conversion website I may use if the code seems, uh, incomprehensible.

Comment: There is a bunch of ListView related scrollbar manipulation shown [in this Q+A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24716049/1070452)  including a Pinvoke to `ShowScrollBar`

Comment: @Plutonix Nice link, but I don't want to resize my columns based on whether a scroll bar appears. I don't want to hide a scroll bar either. I just want them to be present throughout the `ListView`'s lifetime.

Comment: Given that the system appears to want not to do this and that list views work perfectly in their standard form I wonder what your motivation is.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Apart from it looking cool, mostly learning - if other common controls support this why not this one. Also I like to experiment on test subjects (in this case `ListView`) until I hit a wall saying "It can't be done!" or "This is EVIL!". ;) In both these cases I'd just like to know why I shouldn't be doing something that otherwise I might try to do.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan The motivation in this case: I don't want my `ListView` to display partial items. With horizontal scrolling enabled, an integral number of items are shown if I set the size accordingly. This only works with either the scroll bar displayed, or not displayed but not both (default is displaying them as needed). I don't want to disable horizontal scrolling, nor can I dynamically change the size of the `ListView` (it'd be just way too awkward.) So, this is my only option: disable and enable the scroll bars as needed and have them visible throughout the lifetime of the `ListView`.

Comment: You question is much closer to the one I linked than you think.  Each time you add or remove an item, the normal LV behavior is to check if Scrollbars are needed.  So, you will need to do something very ,much like the link and monitor changes to the size and Reissue the call to turn on the VScroll from time to time.

Comment: @Plutonix It is really close, but I need more than that. I needed to show them always. Also, I need them updated whenever it was shown, `Items` are added or removed, __AND__ _when the_ `ListViewGroup` _is expanded or collapsed._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- **Information**:

  - Firstly, I have to admit this is an *okay* answer and not the *best/most efficient* one. If you have a different answer from mine, please post it.
  - Secondly, this answer owes some credit to [Plutonix](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1070452/plutonix)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24722635/4294597), experimenting with which I learned that by default `ListView` does not have `WS_HSCROLL | WS_VSCROLL` flags set in its styles.

    - This is why my previous workaround had problem with themes.
    - These *Classic* scroll bars are ones Windows provides to `Control`s that do not have these flags set.
    - Changing the `CreateParams` does not work either. You have to set it manually in the `OnHandleCreated` method using `SetWindowLong`.
    - The solution I am posting does not use the above technique. Apparently, calling `ShowScrollBar` for each window message forces these flags to be set.
- **The Solution**:

  - Define your `WndProc` like the following:

    ```
    protected override void WndPoc(ref Message m)
    {
    //custom code before calling base.WndProc
    base.WndProc(ref m);
    //custom after base.WndProc returns
    WmScroll(); //VERY INEFFICIENT, called for each message :(
    }
    ```
  - Define WmScroll() as follows:

    ```
    protected virtual void WmScroll()
    {
    NativeMethods.ShowScrollBar(Handle, SB_BOTH, true);
    	
    //si.fMask = SIF_PAGE | SIF_RANGE <- initialized in .ctor
    	
    NativeMethods.GetScrollInfo(Handle, SB_HORZ, ref si);
    if(si.nMax < si.nPage)
    	NativeMethods.EnableScrollBar(Handle, SB_HORZ, ESB_DISABLE_BOTH);
    else
    	NativeMethods.EnableScrollBar(Handle, SB_HORZ, ESB_ENABLE_BOTH);
    NativeMethods.GetScrollInfo(Handle, SB_VERT, ref si);
    if(si.nMax < si.nPage)
    	NativeMethods.EnableScrollBar(Handle, SB_VERT, ESB_DISABLE_BOTH);
    else
    	NativeMethods.EnableScrollBar(Handle, SB_VERT, ESB_ENABLE_BOTH);
    }
    ```
  - **Output**:

It now, looks like:

[image: What I Have]

These are with another item added featuring the horizontal scroll and working `ListViewGroup` collapse button:

[image: Long text left] [image: Long text right]

- **Imperfection**, *yes there is*:

  - A call to `AutoResizeColumns` is required if group collapse changes effective text width, otherwise the vertical scroll bar hides the collapse buttons.

Comment: because I quickly copied the linked text from your post.