# Always shown scroll bar in TListView

Tags: c++, winapi, scrollbar, c++builder-10.2-tokyo

When all items in listview can be visible, scrollbar automatically hides. 
  I could make it always hidden, therefore I have to create own scrollbar.

Is there is way to show it always (when small count of items it would be disenable) ?

Comment: What is the point of showing a scrollbar that can't be scrolled since all of its items are already visible? Why do you need this? There is a reason the scrollbar auto hides itself, it is standard UI behavior for a ListView. Why do you want to go against the standard?

Comment: This is used in AIMP music player, and it is very comfortable for me. I'd like to make same in my music player.

Comment: Related (but for C#): [Force the display of scroll bars in a ListView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39057774/). You might be able to adapt it for `TListView`